# How to stop a process from within the tests, when testing a never-ending process?

Tags: ruby, testing, spawn

I am developing a long-running program in Ruby. I am writing some integration tests for this. These tests need to kill or stop the program after starting it; otherwise the tests hang.

For example, with a file `bin/runner`

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
while true do
  puts "Hello World"
  sleep 10
end
```

The (integration) test would be:

```
class RunReflectorTest < TestCase
  test "it prints a welcome message over and over" do
    out, err = capture_subprocess_io do
      system "bin/runner"
    end
    assert_empty err
    assert_includes out, "Hello World"
  end
end
```

Only, obviously, this will not work; the test starts and never stops, because the `system` call never ends.

How should I tackle this? Is the problem in `system` itself, and would `Kernel#spawn` provide a solution? If so, how? Somehow the following keeps the `out` empty:

```
class RunReflectorTest < TestCase
  test "it prints a welcome message over and over" do
    out, err = capture_subprocess_io do
      pid = spawn "bin/runner"
      sleep 2
      Process.kill pid
    end
    assert_empty err
    assert_includes out, "Hello World"
  end
end
```

. This direction also seems like it will cause a lot of timing-issues (and slow tests). Ideally, a reader would follow the stream of STDOUT and let the test pass as soon as the string is encountered and then immediately kill the subprocess. I cannot find how to do this with `Process`.

Comment: Not sure whether the async approach you mentioned is feasible. But maybe it would work to do it from shell via a [timeout command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161193/bash-script-that-kills-a-child-process-after-a-given-timeout). Or maybe even Ruby's Timeout.timeout method

Comment: "let the test pass as soon as the string is encountered" is a job for IO#expect. https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/expect/rdoc/IO.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the [answer from CodeGnome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44610104/73673) on how to use `Timeout::timeout` and [the answer from andyconhin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44613988/73673) on how to redirect `Process::spawn` IO, I came up with two Minitest helpers that can be used as follows:

```
it "runs a deamon" do
  wait_for(timeout: 2) do
    wait_for_spawned_io(regexp: /Hello World/, command: ["bin/runner"])
  end
end
```

The helpers are:

```
def wait_for(timeout: 1, &block)
  Timeout::timeout(timeout) do
    yield block
  end
rescue Timeout::Error
  flunk "Test did not pass within #{timeout} seconds"
end

def wait_for_spawned_io(regexp: //, command: [])
  buffer = ""

  begin
    read_pipe, write_pipe = IO.pipe
    pid = Process.spawn(command.shelljoin, out: write_pipe, err: write_pipe)

    loop do
      buffer << read_pipe.readpartial(1000)
      break if regexp =~ buffer
    end
  ensure
    read_pipe.close
    write_pipe.close
    Process.kill("INT", pid)
  end

  buffer
end
```

These can be used in a test which allows me to start a subprocess, capture the STDOUT and as soon as it matches the test Regular Expression, it passes, else it will wait 'till timeout and flunk (fail the test).

The `loop` will capture output and pass the test once it sees matching output. It uses a `IO.pipe` because that is most transparant for subprocesses (and their children) to write to.

I doubt this will work on Windows. And it needs some cleaning up of the `wait_for_spawned_io` which is doing slightly too much IMO. Antoher problem is that the `Process.kill('INT')` might not reach the children which are orphaned but still running after this test has ran. I need to find a way to ensure the entire subtree of processes is killed.

Answer (score 1):

### Test Behavior, Not Language Features

First, what you're doing is a TDD anti-pattern. Tests should focus on behaviors of methods or objects, not on language features like loops. If you must test a loop, construct a test that checks for a useful *behavior* like "entering an invalid response results in a re-prompt." There's almost no utility in checking that a loop loops forever.

However, you might decide to test a long-running process by checking to see:

1. If it's still running after *t* time.
2. If it's performed at least *i* iterations.
3. If a loop exits properly given certain input or upon reaching a boundary condition.

### Use Timeouts or Signals to End Testing

Second, if you decide to do it anyway, you can just escape the block with [Timeout::timeout](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/Timeout.html#method-c-timeout). For example:

```
require 'timeout'

# Terminates block
Timeout::timeout(3) { `sleep 300` }
```

This is quick and easy. However, note that using timeout doesn't actually signal the process. If you run this a few times, you'll notice that *sleep* is still running multiple times as a system process.

It's better is to signal the process when you want to exit with [Process::kill](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Process.html#method-c-kill), ensuring that you clean up after yourself. For example:

```
pid = spawn 'sleep 300'
Process::kill 'TERM', pid
sleep 3
Process::wait pid
```

Aside from resource issues, this is a better approach when you're spawning something stateful and don't want to pollute the independence of your tests. You should almost always kill long-running (or infinite) processes in your test teardown whenever you can.

Comment: My simplified example was a bit too condensed: I am not testing "that there is a loop", merely that the loop is there, my tests don't care about it, but "a kind of loop" prohibits the process from stopping itself.

Answer (score 1):

> Ideally, a reader would follow the stream of STDOUT and let the test pass as soon as the string is encountered and then immediately kill the subprocess. I cannot find how to do this with Process.

You can redirect stdout of spawned process to any file descriptor by specifying `out` option

```
pid = spawn(command, :out=>"/dev/null") # write mode
```

[Documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Process.html#method-c-spawn)

[Example of redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10414132/redirecting-stdout-stderr-of-spawn-to-a-string-in-ruby)